# Save custom attribute in order

Tags: magento, attributes, save, custom-attribute

I'm having trouble getting and setting a custom attribute in the order.

I have the following SQL script:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$attribute = array(
    'position'          => 1,
    'type'              => 'text',
    'input'             => 'varchar',
    'label'             => 'My Order Field',
    'global'            => 1,
    'visible'           => 1,
    'required'          => 0,
    'user_defined'      => 1,
    'searchable'        => 0,
    'filterable'        => 0,
    'comparable'        => 0,
    'visible_on_front'  => 1,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
    'unique'            => 0,
    'is_configurable'   => 0,
    'position'          => 1,
);

$setup->addAttribute('order', 'my_order_field', $attribute);

$installer->endSetup();
```

I can see the attribute in the eav table after running this.

I've then setup a observer that runs when a new order has been saved which i've also confirmed is running (with die() statements).

I've now removed those die statements and changed the order save code to this:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$order = $event->getOrder();
$order->setMyOrderField('Hello');
```

And in my admin backend section I've added a row to retrieve the data:

```
    <tr>
        <td class="label"><label><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('My Order Field') ?></label></td>
        <td class="value"><strong><?php echo $_order->getMyOrderField(); ?></strong></td>
    </tr>
```

However when I put a fresh order through nothing appears, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in terms of saving data to my custom attribute?

Thanks

Comment: Is the field available in sales_flat_order table?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$attribute = array(
    'position'          => 1,
    'type'              => 'text',
    'input'             => 'varchar',
    'label'             => 'My Order Field',
    'global'            => 1,
    'visible'           => 1,
    'required'          => 0,
    'user_defined'      => 1,
    'searchable'        => 0,
    'filterable'        => 0,
    'comparable'        => 0,
    'visible_on_front'  => 1,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
    'unique'            => 0,
    'is_configurable'   => 0,
    'position'          => 1,
);


$setup->addAttribute('order', 'my_order_field', $attribute);
$setup->addAttribute('quote', 'my_order_field', $attribute);

$installer->endSetup();
```

and

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$order = $event->getOrder();
$order->setMyOrderField('Hello');
$order->save();
```

Comment: Only 3 letters that are not code, I am pretty sure you can do better to somewhat explain your answer